# How to change cursor position when using iabbrev

Tags: abbreviations

When using `iabbrev` to abbreviate `System.out.println ();` as sysout, I want the cursor to be inside the parenthesis, not at the end of the sentence. Anyway to do this? Also, would it work for multi-line abbrevs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
iabbrev sysout System.out.println ();<Left><Left>
```

Note that unless you plan on adding a space inside the parentheses, you'd want to expand the abbreviation with e.g. `<C-]>`.

Comment: `<c-g>U<left>` is even better to permit redo. Regarding the extra space, `eatchar()` can be used to ignore it. Vim documentation has a note about it near`:h eatchar()` or `:h iab` I don't remember.